# Version of Excel document in VSTO add-in

Tags: excel, vsto, versioning

I use VSTO Excel template based solutions frequently.  One of the things I like about this project type is that I can use cached data sets in the Excel template or worksheet to handle application state that persists after the user saves the file.  However, cached data sets create a problem: the schema of the document is bound to the application version.

This hasn't been a big problem, but I've realized it would be a good idea to create a mechanism that will read the version of the Excel document when it opens in order to detect and handle version incompatibilities.  For example, if my 2.1 plugin opens a 1.5 document, the schema of the cached data will not match what is expected.

Is there a standard or recommended way to version stamp the Excel template or worksheet?  If not, does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use the Worksheet.CustomProperties to persist information like this into my worksheet.  Any information you put into the CustomProperties collection gets saved along with the worksheet and is loaded back along with the worksheet information when you reload the worksheet.

Workbooks also support custom properties, but I think in your case Worksheet.CustomProperties is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, perfect!  Specific to the worksheet and not modifiable by the user.  This is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Great idea - now, can it be automated into the Publish feature in Visual Studio so that the Major, Minor, Revision and Build info get into it?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: you could probably dp that if you saved the version info in the CustomXmlPart. Lots of ways to skin *that* cat.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any standard, but you can consider:

1. The use of a custom document property accessible by `Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties` ([How to: Read from and Write to Document Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e0tda25%28VS.80%29.aspx));
2. A protected cell in the worksheet
   itself;

With the first approach the user could manually change this property or delete it. However the second approach you would have protected cells in the worksheet which, if I recall correctly, will introduce some problems if you want to sort any data in that worksheet.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for, but I think there is something to be said for putting the version stamp in the doc properties.  True, the user can modify the version, but they can also view it, which is a big help for troubleshooting.

Protected cells are necessary in many case but a also a nuisance, and they are specific to a sheet rather than a workbook, so I would prefer the document property solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (how to determine the Excel version from within VSTO code).  I found your question while search for a solution.  What worked for me was the Version property of the Excel Application object.  From within a worksheet:

```
Me.Application.Version
```

or maybe, depending on where you're at

```
Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Version
```

Anyway, the value is "11.0" for Excel 2003 and "12.0" for 2007.

However, on re-reading your issue, you need to know the version that created a workbook.  You might try `Workbook.CalculationVersion`, which "Gets a number that indicates the version of Excel that the workbook was last fully recalculated by. The rightmost four digits are the minor calculation engine version number, and the other digits (on the left) are the major version of Microsoft Office Excel." as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.calculationversion.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I don't need to know which Excel version has created a workbook.  My question relates to the use of cached data sets in a document or template based solution.  What I am trying to do is put a version stamp on the document itself so that I can verify the schema of the cached data.